# How to apply css input last-child?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, webforms

Sorry if my post duplicate. I can't find solution for my problem. I have div tag included 2 ASPXButton. It rendered input[type="submit"] tag when run code. First of input tag work well, the last input tag can't inherit css. Here is my code:

**ASPX**

```
<div class="loginButton">
  <div style="float:left; margin-left:-9px;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="on_off" name="remember" class="on_off_checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="f_help">Remember me</span>
  </div>
  <div class=" pull-right" style="margin-right:-8px;">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <dx:ASPxButton AutoPostBack="false" ID="but_login" CssClass="btn" Native="true" EnableDefaultAppearance="false" runat="server" Text="Login">
        </dx:ASPxButton>
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="forgetpass" CssClass="btn" Native="true" EnableDefaultAppearance="false" runat="server" Text="Forget Pass"></dx:ASPxButton>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-group > .btn.large:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
          border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
}

.btn-group > .btn.large:last-child,
.btn-group > .large.dropdown-toggle {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
          border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
}
```

So what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your classes in CSS don't match with those in the Asp code.

Comment: Now you use inline styling(that's usually not good, it may make your code less readable over time). I would recommend you to move all the styling to css file.

Comment: CssClass="btn" no  large nor dropdown-toggle ?

Comment: @Agares I did but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .btn-group > .btn:first-child
    {
        margin-left: 0;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    }

    .btn-group > .btn:last-child
    {
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more CssClass to 2nd div eg.

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="forgetpass" CssClass="btn newClass" Native="true" EnableDefaultAppearance="false" runat="server" Text="Forget Pass"></dx:ASPxButton>
```

and then add in css

```
.newClass
{
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this concept via css....

```
input[type="checkbox"]:last-child {margin-left:20px;}

input[type="radio"]:last-of-type:checked:after{background-color:#000;}
```

Please focus on  `:last-of-type`